# Plug-in Fat Jar Eclipse não aparece no Export

Tags: java, eclipse, plugin, jar, eclipse-plugin

Preciso extrair um jar "gordo", instalei o Plug-in Fat Jar no eclipse (https://sourceforge.net/projects/fjep/).

Versão do Eclipse: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)

Extrai o jar para a pasta plugins do eclipse e executei o eclipse pelo comando eclipse-clean, conforme orientações : http://fjep.sourceforge.net/

Porém, para exportar devo acessar **File -> Export -> Other -> One Jar Exporter** (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11953381/export-runnable-jars-from-eclipse-without-libraries), mas, no Eclipse não existe a opção **Other** e nenhuma das opções disponiveis tem o Fat Jar , conforme imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: _"Preciso extrair JAR gordo"_ extrair não, exportar. Pergunta, o Runnable JAR (JAR executável) do Eclipse não te atende? Fica nessa tela que você falou, dentro de Java (dentro da pasta, na imagem a pasta não está aberta). Dependendo de como ele é configurado para exportar pode até ser que gere um Fat JAR, acho eu. O que mais tem dentro de Java e de General nessa tela? Outra coisa, isso é uma forma fácil de fazer, mas hoje em dia se usa formas mais automatizadas, como um plugin do Maven para Fat JARs declarado em um projeto Maven, é bom ter isso em mente dependendo do que você precisa.

Comment: Esse link que você citou http://fjep.sourceforge.net/ diz que o Eclipse 3.5 em diante tem uma versão simples de exportar Fat JAR já integrada, no export Runnable JAR, então se estiver usando uma versão recente do Eclipse não precisaria do plugin. Acho que é justamente a funcionalidade que falei, irão aparecer três (acho) opções de integração das libraries no JAR, tem que escolher uma delas.

Comment: _Pergunta, o Runnable JAR (JAR executável) do Eclipse não te atende?_ Não atende,pois , só funciona executando pelo terminal (java - jar meujar.jar), abrindo-o ele nao faz transição de telas e gostaria que fizesse para funcionar como um .exe. 


_O que mais tem dentro de Java e de General nessa tela?_ General: An BuildFiles, Archive File , File System e Preferences.
Java: JAR file, Javadoc e Runnablea Jar file

Quanto ao maven nunca utilizei.

Comment: Até onde sei, um Fat JAR ou Über JAR é simplesmente um JAR com todas as dependências dentro, diferente dos convencionais que as dependências (como bibliotecas) ficam de fora. Ele continua sendo um JAR e não um .exe, e portanto roda com `java -jar` ou duplo clique se o tipo do arquivo JAR estiver associado à instalação do Java no sistema. Não é isso?

Comment: Não entendi se você quer um .exe "standalone" que a gente chama (pra dar duplo-clique e rodar direto a sua aplicação) ou um instalador (desses com _wizard_) para a sua aplicação (pois você citou transição de telas). Para o primeiro caso acho que a http://www.graalvm.org/ é uma opção que ouvi falar, não sei se a mais apropriada porque não tenho experiência com esse cenário, então veja também outras. O instalador se precisar seria uma necessidade extra, pois além da aplicação ser executável teria que criar o executável instalador para ela, que pode ser feito em outras linguagens/ferramentas.

Comment: Preciso de um jar ou um .exe que funcione com duplo clique. O Jar comum não atende, pois não faz a transição de telas.. E quando o converti em .exe , há o mesmo problema não faz a transição de telas.

Comment: Não sei se já resolveu o seu problema, só passei para comentar que de acordo com a pergunta mais popular sobre converter para .exe no SO em inglês a própria JDK vem com o `javapackager` que gera código nativo, me parece uma boa opção. Esse problema de transição de telas parece ser alguma exceção que ocorre por falta de alguma biblioteca no programa que está rodando, teria que dar um jeito de investigar melhor as exceções que o programa gera, ou melhorar ele para logar as exceções mesmo que seja na saída-padrão (`System.out`).

Comment: Não resolvi ainda, vou ver nessa questão a que você refere.
É não apresenta nenhum exceção .